# HTML tag wrapping screen (by default) + content (if overflows)

Tags: html, css

I have learnt that if you want to make that a webpage will wrap all the content of your webpage, you should leave the `width` property of your `html` tag alone so the `height` will adapt automatically to the content.

The problem is that, in my case, I need that the content will be dynamic so it depends on how much items I have on the webpage, the webpage needs to wrap all of them.

If there are enough items that overflows the 100% of the screen of my computer there is not any problem because the webpage automatically adapts to its content but when I have less items than the 100% of the screen of my computer, it only adapts to the content so the `html` tag leaves some space without covering it.

I would like that in the cases that the content will be more than the 100% of the screen, the webpage will adapt to it and in cases that the content will be less than the 100%, the `html` tag will cover the full screen(as if I had set `height: 100%;`).

Here some examples:

- [Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/jdpwon6f/1/): Covering all the content. > `OK`.
- [Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/jdpwon6f/2/). Covering only the content, not the full screen. > `NOT OK`.
- [Example 3](https://jsfiddle.net/jdpwon6f/3/). Covering the full screen when the content is less than 100% screen. > `OK`.
- [Example 4](https://jsfiddle.net/jdpwon6f/4/). Covering the full screen but not the full content. > `NOT OK`.

Notice that `Example 1` and `Example 2` does not have `height: 100%;` property and that the `Example 3` and `Example 4` have it.

How can I set the properties of my `CSS` so the `html` tag will cover both screen (by default) and content (if it overflows)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Vucko It does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/jdpwon6f/5/

Comment: Add it to the container - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdpwon6f/6/)

Comment: @Vucko Thank you very much! Exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @MrLister Thank you for your comment. I notice now that in the second example, for example, I set `background-color: whatever` it would covers the full screen. I though that the `flex` item would adapt to the full `html` tag so it is why I though that the `html` tag was not covering the full screen when the content is less than 100% of the screen. @Vucko points me on the correct way and makes the `flex` item with `min-height` as the screen. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use `min-height` with `vh` as a unit:

```
#container{
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdpwon6f/6/)

However, be aware of `vh` browser support - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length).

Comment: I only have a question: Why if I set `min-height: 100vh` to my `html` and `body` tags and I set `height: 100%` on my `#container` it does not make the same behaviour as if I set direclty `min-height: 100vh` to the container? If the `html` tag has as `min-height` the viewport I think that the container should get the 100% of the height. Here the example I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/jdpwon6f/7/

Comment: Seems when using `min-height` for `html` that also is `height` required - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czwwzr24/). Also, when havin a fixed value also doesn't work - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czwwzr24/2/). I'd make a new question with this topic on your place :)

Comment: Yes, I think it should be an interesting theme to ask for. Feel free to make a new question. If finally you do not make it, I think I will ask it later :)

Comment: Also, `body` has some issues - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czwwzr24/4/), and both `html` and `body` are `block` elements. I'd recommend to use some wrapper element and style only it - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czwwzr24/5/). Yea, it sure is interesting :) No worries, I'll wait for you to ask :)

Comment: Look that if you set on your `body` tag `height: 0px` the `#wrapper` will also wraps all the screen. It seems that it does not matter how much bigger the `body` tag is.